# Upgrading from Access 2003 to Access 2007 and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, migration

I am maintaining a pretty large Access 2003 project with a MDB data file on the server and linked tables. The plan is to upgrade to Access 2007 (or even 2010) and SQL Server as the data storage.

As this is a two-step plan, which of these steps is best done first? Does it make a difference if I first upgrade to 2007, or should I link to SQL first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter. 
I would go to access 2007, let the 2007 do the migration, check everything, and then go for the sql server.
But - nothing will happen if you take the other way.
I think it will be easier to disconnect the mdb and connect to SQL in Access 2007, Rather than in 2003.

Comment: +1 Does 2007 have better support for migration to SQL server? 2003 has the Upsizing Wizard, that is what I have used, but I don't have a lot of experience with 2007.

Comment: Depends on your version of SQL Server. If it's 2005, A2007 will have a better upsizing result than A2003 (which predates SQL 2005). If it's 2008, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to read [Allen Browne](http://allenbrowne.com/Access2007.html) for additional information on the conversion to 2007.